# Cow's vs Cows' milk - which is correct?

Tags: possessives

1. All of the cow's milk will be gathered and consumed.
2. All of the cows' milk will be gathered and consumed.

Comment: Is it referring to all of the milk of one cow or many cows?

Comment: It doesn't mention it in the question.

Comment: Either is correct, but they mean subtly different things. See the linked question and its answers.

Comment: I expect << cows milk >> to become an acceptable version at some point in time for essentially the open compound analogue of _coconut milk_ / _soya milk_. I think the transition to << cow milk >> would be too jarring in speech. This is in line with the competing << writers guilds >> and the prevailing << working mens clubs >> (new word!) But for the time being, the type of milk is almost always << cow's milk >> or << cows' milk >> (both are used) while the possessive (this brown cow's milk; the Giles's cows' milk) forms are formed regularly.